# URL in Flow Screen open in same window but new Console Tab

Tags: formula, visual-workflow, hyperlink

I am creating a Flow that will only be shown to Users within a Lightning Component on a Lightning Page.

It cycles through a lot of loops and eventually displays a list of records with some other information regarding them.  However, I would like each of these records to be a link to that Record's page. I would also like it to instead of opening up in a new browser tab, to instead open up in a new Console tab within the same browser tab.

My first iteration was adding the following as a link URL within the Text Template I'm using: "https://my.domain.salesforce.com/{!thisRecord.Id}". This resulted in the Record's page opening up as expected, but in a different Browser tab.  It had a new Console tab but my goal is to avoid the user having then two browser tabs open with essentially the same info and then needing to close one.

I then read up about using "_self" and "_parent" targets in the HYPERLINK() formula. So I created a formula variable that uses the following formula:

```
HYPERLINK("/" & {!thisRecord.Id},"","_self")
```

I then added that variable into the link url part of the Text Template.  This resulted in the same thing where the record opened up in a new Browser Tab, however instead of opening the record I wanted, it opened the original record that started the flow even though the variable I'm getting the ID from is totally seperate. I ran the Flow Debug and made sure that {!thisRecord.Id} is populated correctly right before the link is created, but clicking it still takes me to the wrong record.

Does anyone have any advice on getting the result of clicking the link and having the record page open up in a new Console tab but within the same Browser tab?

Comment: Is the issue fixed and how?

Comment: Is it fixed any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

Create a formula field on the object that you are linking to:

```
HYPERLINK("/"&Id, CaseNumber ,"_parent" )
```

And get that field of the record you are trying to link on a display text element in flow